# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException on Context lookup Java

Tags: java, datasource, jndi, java-ee-8

I'm using a Payara application server on which I have defined a connection pool in order to lookup after it in my application. The ping made from application server to database works.

In my domain.xml database resource is configured as follows:

```
<jdbc-resource pool-name="MasterPool" jndi-name="jdbc/master"></jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource40" name="MasterPool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      ...
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
```

The setup of Context is made on servlet init method.

```
public void init() throws ServletException {

        Context env = null;
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
        try {
            env = new InitialContext(ht);
            pool = (DataSource) env.lookup("master");
            System.out.println("Data source found");
        }
        catch(NamingException ne) {
            throw new ServletException(ne);
        }


    }
```

Can you give some insight about the message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: master
```

I've tried to make the lookup after jdbc/master and java:/comp/env/jdbc/master

Regards,

Comment: created glassfish-web.xml in WEB-INF <!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">

<resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/master</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>jdbc/master</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
</glassfish-web-app>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have below line in **META-INF/context.xml**

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
         ......
      name="master" // this line is important      
        .......    
/>
```

Comment: I have added the following entries into web.xml   <resource-ref>
<description>DB Connection</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/master</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

Comment: I'm still getting the NameNotfoundException

Comment: is META-INF/context.xml, not web.xml